# How Can I fix a broken hose?

Tags: sprinkler-system, hose

My wife and I recently bought a house, and we discovered there were buried hoses near all of our hose nozzles. We turned them on and to our surprise they were tied to sprinkler heads throughout the yard.

Anyway, one hose was broken (as shown in the pictures below) and because of how the hoses are used and they're buried, it'd be nice to be able to fix it without having to dig the entire hose up. How can we fix a hose like this?

[image: Broken Hose][image: Broken Hose]

Comment: Cut end cleanly, install new end fitting. Or install splice fitting. Both should be available from any hardware store.  Before going shopping, measure the inside diameter of the hose so you get the right size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are garden hose splice devices that you can purchase at home centers and big box stores that can be used to fix these. You may lose a short bit of total length as you cut off the damaged part to accomodate the splicer.

[image]

If you need more added length you could use two of these splicers to stitch in a new length of hose.

They also sell devices that will attach new hose ends as well.

In your situation the hose ends that are broken may be broken from having laid out in the sun for years at a time. The sun treatment can make the hose hard and  brittle. On the other hand the part of the hose in the soil may still be in decent shape. You could cut off the old hose all the way back to where it is in the soil and splice on a piece cut from a new hose that already has the faucet tap fitting on the end.

Be aware that the direct attachment of your lawn sprinklers to the the potable water supply is not the recommended guideline. Sprinklers are generally connected through anti siphon valves (whether those be manually operated or solenoid controlled). You may want to look into replacing the temporary hose connect hack with a more permanent arrangement with some anti siphon valves. Note that the anti siphon valve should be installed at an elevation that is 8 to 12 inches above the highest sprinkler outlet on that water circuit.

[image]

Comment: What does an anti siphon valve do for me? I'll probably do it, just wondering what the advantage is

Comment: The anti siphon valve prevents any possible back flow from the outbound water lines back into the potable water supply. The sprinkler lines could get dirt, fungus, bacteria etc etc in them. Under some circumstances there could be a loss of pressure from the potable water source and without a mechanism to cause an air break in the line it is possible that water can backflow by siphon action into the source water lines. Not a good thing to have happen. There could also be normal usage scenarios where sprinklers are in use and a reverse pressure surge happens when another  (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) branch of the water system is suddenly turned on or a water line breaks. This situation could also result in some siphon action.

Comment: @DanDrews Around here, code requires a backflow preventer (an alternative to an anti-siphone valve), tested yearly, on sprinkler systems. You probably want to look into what the requirements are there.